# Two answers using exactly the same source to answer the same question -- Does that make the answer posted later flag-able as not an answer?

Tags: support, answers, sources-and-citations, flagging

Let's suppose I have posted an answer A to a question Q using some texts T as reference. Now, some hours later, another user posts another answer B to the same question Q using exactly the same texts T as reference and arrived at the same conclusion of A.

Does that make the answer B flag-able as not an answer? I remember reading something like that earlier but unable to locate that post now.

Comment: B sounds duplicate answer if it's copying A and it [can be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155160/260388).

Comment: That means if a portion of an answer is suffering from the same issue, that portion has to be removed? @Pandya

Comment: If this was posted in connection to your comments [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42419/was-vivekananda-a-proponent-of-birth-based-caste-system-or-the-gun%cc%a3a-based/42422#comment131187_42422), then you are misrepresenting facts and accusing users of "stealing" your references. 'a portion of an answer is suffering from the same issue, that portion has to be removed' - if this is your main issue, it needs to be part of the question itself.

Comment: "then you are misrepresenting facts and accusing users of "stealing" your references"  --- I am not doing any of these as I have not mentioned about any particular post in my question here. " it needs to be part of the question itself" -- let me decide what should be part of one my questions.